# Visual Studio 2017 not support targeting .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, sdk, visual-studio-2017, .net-core-3.0

I have tried installing SDK 3.0.1 in Visual Studio 2017 --version 15.9.16. When I open a new web application I get an error saying:

"***Severity Code Description   Project File Line Suppression State Error NETSDK1045 The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.0. Either target .NET Core 2.2 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.0. IdentityServer-C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\sdk\2.2.106\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets 137***"

My Dotnet Info:

```
 dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.0.100
 Commit:    04339c3a26

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17763
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.0.0
  Commit:  7d57652f33

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  1.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.500 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.502 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.505 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.509 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.105 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.106 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 doesn't support .net core 3. You need Visual Studio 2019 16.3 or higher. [Source](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-0/)

Comment: This question shouldn't be downvoted nor closed. This is in fact pretty useful for futur readers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Visual Studio 2017 doesn't support .NET Core 3. You need Visual Studio 2019 16.3 or higher. You can find this information in the [.NET Core 3.0 announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-0/).

> Visual Studio 2019 16.3 and Visual Studio for Mac 8.3 were also released [on 23 september 2019] and are required update to use .NET Core 3.0 with Visual Studio.

**Some more useful links:**

- [Announcement for Visual Studio 2019 16.3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/dot-net-core-support-in-visual-studio-2019-version-16-3/)
- [Visual Studio download-page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/de/downloads/)